# When do you need to run mongod?

Tags: mongodb

Within mongo atlas, there is a connection string that is provided in their UI, which I have just been pasting into my terminal. Basically it is something like `mongo "connection string" --username userName`. This starts up the mongo shell and allows me to automatically connect with my cluster.

I've been reading up on mongod, and from what I understand, it is like the mongodb server, handling all the requests, responses, server operations, whatever, in the background. I can type this command in my terminal, and then type in `mongo` on a different terminal to start a shell, and connect to mongod this way.

However, I've never had to use mongod at all by using just the connection string as I talked about above. Why is this? When is it necessary to start `mongod`?

Comment: `mongod` is the server process. Just imagine Atlas running it for you. You'd only need to run it when running your own instance of MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

Atlas is cloud-based platform that runs and manages `mongod` as well as `mongos` and other for you. You need to use `mongod` only if you're going to launch/manage/support db yourself.

Comment: when would you want to launch/manage/support a db yourself, instead of letting Atlas do it?

Comment: see https://www.beekeeper.io/blog/onpremise-vs-cloud-benefits-saas/